# Login and registration using servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, html, servlets

So I am trying to make a login servlet and a registration servlet. But I can't seem to get it to work.

I am trying to make an online-shop where you have to login before you can begin shopping. I'm new at web app development, so please bear with me.

Here's my code:

Login:

```js
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
        {
            
            String username = request.getParameter("userName");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            
            if(!username.equals("") && !password.equals(""))
            {
                for(Customer c : Data.getCustomers())
                {
                    if(c.getUserName().equals(username) && c.getPasword().equals(password))
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect("Catalogue.html");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                        out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<head>");
                        out.println("<title>Invalid username or password</title>");            
                        out.println("</head>");
                        out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<h1>Ooops, something went wrong</h1>");
                        out.println("<h2><b>Wrong username or password.</b></h2>");
                        out.println("<h2>Please </h2>");
                        out.println("<form>"
                                + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Try again\""
                                + "onClick=\"history.go(-1);"
                                + "return true; \"></form>\"");
                        out.println("</body>");
                        out.println("</html>");  
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

Registration:

```js
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
        {
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String username = request.getParameter("userName");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            Customer c = new Customer(firstname, lastname, username, password, email);

            if (request.getParameter("register") != null)
            {

equals("") || username.equals("") || password.equals("") || email.equals(""))
                {

                    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                    out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                    out.println("<title>Missing info</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");
                    out.println("<body>");
                    out.println("<h1>Ooops, something went wrong</h1>");
                    out.println("<h2><b>Please fill out all the fields to register.</b></h2>");
                    out.println("<form>"
                            + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Try again\""
                            + "onClick=\"history.go(-1);return true; \"></form>");
                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("</html>");
                } else
                {

                    for (Customer customer : Data.getCustomers())
                    {
                        if (!username.equals(customer.getUserName()) &&       !password.equals(customer.getPasword()))
                        {
                            Data.addNewCustomer(firstname, lastname, username, password, email);
                 
                            response.sendRedirect("Catalogue.html");
                            
                        } else
                        {

                            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                            out.println("<html>");
                            out.println("<head>");
                            out.println("<title>Invalid username</title>");
                            out.println("</head>");
                            out.println("<body>");
                            out.println("<h1>Ooops, try again!</h1>");
                            out.println("<h2><b>Username already in use</b></h2>");
                            out.println("<h2>Please choose another one and</h2>");
                            out.println("<form>"
                                    + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Try again\""
                                    + "onClick=\"history.go(-1);"
                                    + "return true; \"></form>");
                            out.println("</body>");
                            out.println("</html>");

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

HTML Login:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>Login</h1></center>
    <form action="LoginServlet"
          method="post">
        <center><dl> 
            <dt><b>Please fill in your username and password to login: </b></dt>
            <dd>Username: 
            <input type="text" name="userName"></dd>
            <dd>Password: 
            <input type="password" name="password"></dd>
            </dl></center>
    <center>
        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
        
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <b>If you don't have an account, please </b>
        <a href='Registration.html'>register</a><b>.</b>
        
        <br><br><br><img src="online-shop.jpg">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML registration:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body> 
    <center><h1>Register</h1></center>
    <form method="post" action="RegistrationServlet">
        <center><dl> 
            <dt><b>Please fill in the information below to register: </b></dt>
            <dd>Firstname:
            <input type="text" name="firstName"></dd>
            <dd>Lastname:
            <input type="text" name="lastName"></dd>
            <dd>Username:
                <input type="text" name="userName"></dd>
            <dd>Password:
                <input type="password" name="password"></dd>
            <dd>E-mail:
                <input type="text" name="email"></dd>
            </dl></center>
    <center>
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Submit" >
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Cancel" >
        
        <br><br><br><img src="online-shop.jpg">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: that's a pretty big wall of code you're asking for help with.  What,  exactly,  isn't working about it? What have you done to diagnise the problem? What test cases pass and what related tests fail?

Comment: It doesn't redirect to my Catalogue.html file. And I've tried debugging, but it doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.
When I try to login or register a new user, it doesn't redirect. It just shows an empty html page

Comment: nDoes the login/registration,  itself seem to work? If you log in with a bad username/password does it work as expected? If you add some log messages to a log file (even stdout),  what is the last thing that successfully happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could put in some logging to check at least

1. that your servlets are being triggered at all,
2. what request parameter values they are receiving, and
3. the data to which those parameters are being compared.

I think you will find, though, that when `Data.getCustomers()` returns zero customers, each of your servlets falls out the bottom of its `processRequest()` method without either sending a redirect or printing anything to the response's output stream.  (Except that the registration servlet will send its error response if any form fields are left empty).

Moreover, I think you will find that your servlets fail in interesting ways when you do have customers.  They both scan the provided customers and perform action *for each one*.  What you really want is different: look up an existing customer matching the given username (without regard to password); then take action (including checking the password) based on whether the *overall lookup* succeeded.  Perhaps instead of retrieving and looping over all the customers, it would be more convenient to add a method `Data.getCustomerByUsername(String)`.  If you can't do that, then you could instead add an analogous method to your servlet classes.

Comment: Thanks. I did make a method to get the customers by username. And I found the error. It was in my ArrayList when I tried to add a new customer. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
once try like this

out.println("<form><a href=\"catalogue.html\">link</a></form></body></html>");
```